# How to remove scene world colour completely?

Tags: color-management

I've been struggling to remove this pink overlay, I'm not sure what I've clicked for it to be this way and I've tried everything, Please help.[image]

Comment: open your Shader Editor, switch it to World instead of Object, and see what is your node setup, does it have an Environment Texture plugged into the Background node?

Comment: If you only want to remove it from the Viewport rendered mode display, simply deselect the Scene World Check box.

Comment: Thank you so much , I realised I didn't install my hdri's . Thanks for the help, truly appreciate it.